# CoffeeScript and OOP - prototype methods

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

Let's say I do the following code:

```
class Test
  t: ->
    "hell"
  d: ->
    console.log t()
    "no"
```

It will compile to something like:

```
(function() {
  this.Test = (function() {
    function Test() {}
    Test.prototype.t = function() {
      return "hell";
    };
    Test.prototype.d = function() {
      console.log(t());
      return "no";
    };
    return Test;
  })();
}).call(this);
```

Ok, I can't call the method `t()` inside the `d()` method.

Why not? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class Test
  t: ->
    "hell"
  d: ->
    console.log @t()
    #           ^ Added
    "no"
```

In CoffeeScript, as in Javascript, methods on the prototype must be accessed as properties of `this`.  CoffeeScript has shorthand for `this`, the `@` character.  `@t()` compiles to `this.t()`.  And `this.t()` will execute `Test.prototype.t()` in the context on the instance you called it on.

Comment: gotcha. I need to tell to use this instance method, otherwise it will try to use a static method. Am I right? BTW: Thanks

Comment: @caarlos0 Not quite. `@t()` will execute an instance method, but `t()` won't access a static method on the class. `t()` looks for a local variable function shared in the current closure scope, and tries to execute it. This is neither a instance or static method, it's simply a local variable. And in this code, there is no local variable `t` anywhere.